# One-To-One Questions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a few questions relating to one-to-one.  I felt like I knew these concepts back when they were paired with $\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$, but now I have some questions that don't specify $\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$.

1) Suppose that $A$ is a $9 \times 5$ matrix that $T(x) = Ax$ is a linear transformation.  Then $T$ can be one-to-one?

2) Suppose that $A$ is a $4 \times13$ matrix that $T(x) = Ax$ is a linear transformation.  Then $T$ can be one-to-one?

Seeing the questions like this is a bit confusing.  My guesses are:

1) True
2) False

My guesses come from a theorem that states, "Let $T$ be a linear transformation.  Then $T$ is one-to-one if and only if $T(x) = 0$ has only the trivial solution $x = 0$;

In the first case of a $9 \times 5$ vector.  Because each vector has $9$ elements, it is possible for the system to reduce down to $5 \times 5$ (in the case where the other $4$ cancel out), making the system linearly independent, and therefore, one-to-one.

In the second case of $4 \times 13$, its impossible to have a linearly independent system, as free variables will be there no matter what.  Because of that, $T(x) = 0$ isn't from a trivial solution, so it is not one-to-one.

Would anyone be able to confirm or deny in the simplest terms possible?  Im still struggling with this very much.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that an $m \times n$ represents a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$.  The size of the matrix tells you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full answer depends on stating what the domain and range sets are. After I explain, I'll say why.

In general, an $m \times n$ matrix, viewed as a linear transformation (via matrix multiplication) maps $n$-dimensional vectors into $m$-dimensional vectors.

If $n > m$, there is simply no way you can preserve linear independence of the images of a basis set under the linear map; the target space only has $m$ basis vectors, and since it is a basis, it has MAXIMAL size (and $n$ is larger). This means if $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis for the domain, the set $\{T(v_1),\dots, T(v_n)\}$ must be linearly dependent, which means in turn that some non-zero vector:

$c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n$ maps to the linear combination:

$c_1T(v_1) + \cdots + c_nT(v_n) = 0$, so $T$ is not injective (because $T(0) = 0$ as well).

If $n \leq m$, it's possible $T$ is injective, but it doesn't have to be.

Basically, an injective linear map takes an $n$-dimensional space, to another $n$-dimensional space. If the target space has fewer dimensions, the image "won't fit" unless the linear map is for some vectors, "many-to-one"(not injective).

So, your answers, by this reasoning, are correct.

However, it is possible to have a $9 \times 5$ matrix represent an injective mapping-*provided* we restrict it's domain to a $5$-dimensional subspace of a $9$-dimenisonal subspace, and its range has *at least* dimension $5$. For example, if:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$,

then $T_A$ maps the $5$-dimensional subspace $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,0,0,0,0): x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5 \in \Bbb R\}$ of $\Bbb R^9$ injectively onto $\Bbb R^5$.

Comment: Just a quick question, when we state m x n, m represents the vertical height of the matrix and n represents the amount of vectors in the matrix, correct?